# I keep getting an internal server error(code 500) every time I try to use big query client SDK

Tags: node.js, express, google-bigquery

i am trying to create a table in my Bigquery dataset by calling the create_table API from my app using a node.js Bigquery client SDK but I keep getting an internal server error with error code 500, every time I try to access it using my API, here is my code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");


const express = require('express');
const app = express();
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
app.use(cors);


var schema;
var table_id = 'its meeeee';

app.post('/create_table', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);



    if (req.body.t1 != null) {

        schema = [
            { name: req.body.t1, type: req.body.v1 },

        ]



    } else if (req.body.t1 && req.body.t2 != null) {

        schema = [
            { name: req.body.t1, type: req.body.v1 },
            { name: req.body.t2, type: req.body.v2 },

        ]



    } else if (req.body.t1 && req.body.t2 && req.body.t3 != null) {

        schema = [
            { name: req.body.t1, type: req.body.v1 },
            { name: req.body.t2, type: req.body.v2 },
            { name: req.body.t3, type: req.body.v3 },

        ]

    } else if (req.body.t1 && req.body.t2 && req.body.t3 && req.body.t4 != null) {

        schema = [
            { name: req.body.t1, type: req.body.v1 },
            { name: req.body.t2, type: req.body.v2 },
            { name: req.body.t3, type: req.body.v3 },
            { name: req.body.t4, type: req.body.v4 },

        ]



    } else if (req.body.t1 && req.body.t2 && req.body.t3 && req.body.t4 && req.body.t5 != null) {

        schema = [
            { name: req.body.t1, type: req.body.v1 },
            { name: req.body.t2, type: req.body.v2 },
            { name: req.body.t3, type: req.body.v3 },
            { name: req.body.t4, type: req.body.v4 },
            { name: req.body.t5, type: req.body.v5 },


        ]


    }


    'use strict';


    function main(
        datasetId = 'gamelot-c057c:denanse', // Existing dataset
        tableId = table_id, // Table to be created

    ) {
        // [START bigquery_create_table]
        // Import the Google Cloud client library and create a client
        const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
        const bigquery = new BigQuery();

        async function createTable() {
            // Creates a new table named "my_table" in "my_dataset".

            /**
             * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
             */
            // const datasetId = "my_dataset";
            // const tableId = "my_table";
            // const schema = 'Name:string, Age:integer, Weight:float, IsMagic:boolean';

            // For all options, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource
            const options = {
                schema: schema,
                location: 'US',
            };

            // Create a new table in the dataset
            const [table] = await bigquery
                .dataset(datasetId)
                .createTable(tableId, options);

            console.log(`Table ${table.id} created.`);
        }
        // [END bigquery_create_table]
        createTable();
    }
    main(...process.argv.slice(2));

});
```

..........................................................................................................

Comment: I mean, `its meeeee` isn't a valid table name, but I'd expect the error code to indicate user error of some form in that case.  Does the 500 come with a structured error response?

Comment: even after removing the space i still keep getting a response of an internal server error, I'm kind of new to big query, is there a way I can catch the specific error?